# Name of the apk of the google playstore

Tags: android, google-play-services

What is the name of the apk of the Google Playstore ("the package name is com.android.vending")? More specifically, I try to find the apk in the device (in system/app or system/priv-app) but i do not find it.

Comment: https://www.apkshub.com/app/com.android.vending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's
/system/priv-app/Phonesky/Phonesky